# In Oracle, how can I view another schema's trigger code if it's not available in ALL_SOURCE?

Tags: oracle, triggers

My program logs into an Oracle DB with the FOO user ID. It needs to retrieve the source code for the triggers in the BAR schema but the triggers are not accessible from the ALL_SOURCE table (I'm guessing due to provisioning). I **can** view the source code using Toad for Oracle, so I'm assuming there's some other method I can use to retrieve the trigger source code.

When I execute the query:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT owner
  2  FROM all_triggers;
```

I get these results, which is what I expected:

```
OWNER
------------------------------
FOO
BAR
```

When I execute the query:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT owner
  2  FROM all_source;
```

I don't get the expected results of "SYS, FOO, BAR". Instead, I get:

```
OWNER
------------------------------
SYS
FOO
```

My program can't have access to login to the BAR schema so I can't use that and the USER_SOURCE table.

Since I can view the source in Toad for Oracle, the FOO schema has some sort of access to view the code, but I don't know how it's doing it. How can my program retrieve BAR's trigger source code?

**Edit:** I do not have access to DBA_SOURCE.

Comment: Do you have access to `dba_source`?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: I suppose that `GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO FOO` would enable you to see the trigger both in `all_triggers` and `all_source`. Any chance for FOO to get that privilege granted?

Comment: Not in production, which is where this will eventually be run against.

Comment: While it is strange that you must be able to read the trigger source codes in a production app at all, I suppose you could write a function in the BAR schema that returns them. Then all FOO needs is an execution right on that BAR function.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That's a workaround I hadn't thought of. Thanks. I wish I could've learned, though, from where Toad is reading the code.

Comment: I'm sure Toad can only see USER/ALL/DBA_SOURCE.